# Building with vite in production mode only results in not being able to read the properties in my vue components

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

With a fairly boilerplate application using Laravel 9, Vue3, InertiaJs and Vite, various components cannot access their properties in when built in production mode.   For example the component:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    copyrightYear: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});
</script>
<template>
    <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto py-12 px-4 overflow-hidden sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <nav class="-mx-5 -my-2 flex flex-wrap justify-center">
                <div class="px-5 py-2">
                    <a href="#" class="text-base leading-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                        About
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="px-5 py-2">
                    <a :href="route('blog.index')" class="text-base leading-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                        Blog
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="px-5 py-2">
                    <a :href="route('contact.create')" class="text-base leading-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="px-5 py-2">
                    <a href="#" class="text-base leading-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                        Jobs
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="px-5 py-2">
                    <a href="#" class="text-base leading-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                        Partners
                    </a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="mt-8 flex justify-center">
                <a href="{{ $page->linkedInUrl }}" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                    <span class="sr-only">Visit us on LinkedIn&reg;</span>
                    <img class="h-6 w-7 opacity-50 hover:opacity-75" src="/img/LI-In-Bug-grayscale.webp">
                </a>
                <a href="{{ $page->gitlabUrl }}" class="ml-6 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                    <span class="sr-only">GitLab</span>
                    <svg fill="currentColor" class="h-7 w-7" viewBox="0 0 586 559">
                        <path fillrule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                            d="m461.48 298.35l-17.78-54.63a7.72 7.72 0 0 0 -.43 -1.47l-35.67-109.8a14.18 14.18 0 0 0 -13.54 -9.67 13.94 13.94 0 0 0 -13.38 9.75l-34 104.63h-107.31l-34.05-104.63a13.94 13.94 0 0 0 -13.32 -9.75h-.08a14.22 14.22 0 0 0 -13.5 9.76l-35.7 109.93c0 .1-.08.18-.11.28l-18.1 55.61a20.29 20.29 0 0 0 7.37 22.71l156.38 113.63a8 8 0 0 0 9.45 -.05l156.41-113.58a20.28 20.28 0 0 0 7.36 -22.72m-233.75-45.13l43.59 134.16-104.64-134.16m148.05 134.19l41.8-128.62 1.8-5.57h61.1l-94.67 121.28m69.44-231.67l30.63 94.33h-61.31m-22.03 16l-30.37 93.46-18.12 55.66-48.42-149.12m-52.73-110.33l30.69 94.33h-61.27m-19.98 70.97a4.31 4.31 0 0 1 -1.56 -4.83l13.44-41.3 98.57 126.37m192.98-80.24l-110.46 80.21.37-.48 98.2-125.86 13.44 41.28a4.31 4.31 0 0 1 -1.55 4.84" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="{{ $page->githubUrl }}" class="ml-6 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                    <span class="sr-only">GitHub</span>
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M12 2C6.477 2 2 6.484 2 12.017c0 4.425 2.865 8.18 6.839 9.504.5.092.682-.217.682-.483 0-.237-.008-.868-.013-1.703-2.782.605-3.369-1.343-3.369-1.343-.454-1.158-1.11-1.466-1.11-1.466-.908-.62.069-.608.069-.608 1.003.07 1.531 1.032 1.531 1.032.892 1.53 2.341 1.088 2.91.832.092-.647.35-1.088.636-1.338-2.22-.253-4.555-1.113-4.555-4.951 0-1.093.39-1.988 1.029-2.688-.103-.253-.446-1.272.098-2.65 0 0 .84-.27 2.75 1.026A9.564 9.564 0 0112 6.844c.85.004 1.705.115 2.504.337 1.909-1.296 2.747-1.027 2.747-1.027.546 1.379.202 2.398.1 2.651.64.7 1.028 1.595 1.028 2.688 0 3.848-2.339 4.695-4.566 4.943.359.309.678.92.678 1.855 0 1.338-.012 2.419-.012 2.747 0 .268.18.58.688.482A10.019 10.019 0 0022 12.017C22 6.484 17.522 2 12 2z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-8">
                <p class="text-center text-base leading-6 text-gray-400">
                    &copy; {{ this.copyrightYear }} , All Rights Reserved
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Throws the following error in the console: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'copyrightYear')`

- Enabled DevTools: The Inertia variables are making it into the vue model.
- Analyzed the vite.config.js configuration to find that it's exactly the same as Laravel's (except for enabling devtools).
- Debugged the generated code and the values are there, but it's not exactly clean and easy to walk.

Comment: `{{ this.copyrightYear }}` should just be `{{ copyrightYear }}`. You don't put `this` in the Vue component HTML, it's assumed (and you're basically doing `this.this.copyrightYear` as a result).

Comment: Good catch.  Sometimes just a second set of eyes will catch something like that.  What boggles my mind is that it's been working in when building in dev mode. I messed with that variable a lot.  Started with `$page.props.copyrightYear` and progressed down to passing it as a property and must have had a senior moment.